# Getting error message when trying to start a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I have been using VMWare on Windows for a long time. But after a long wait, I moved to VirtualBox on Ubuntu 11.10. I installed Ubuntu, 32 Bit, installed all available updates and installed Virtual Box. When I try to create a new Windows installation inside VirtualBox, I got the following error messages.

```
VirtualBox - Error

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP.
The virtual machine '**Windows XP**' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
Details

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
Machine
Interface:
IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}
```

2nd error dialogue

```
Virtualbox - Error in suplibOsinit
Kernal driver not installed (rc--1908)
Please install the virtualbox-dkmbs package and execute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.
```

- I have already tried reinstalling VirtualBox.
- Google result seem to indicate the the problem happens due to Kernel updates.

Is there anyway I can get this working? I need this for malware analysis and if VirtualBox is going to crash on me all the time, then I won't be able to use Ubuntu for work.

Output to dpkg -l | grep virtual

```
 server
rc  virtualbox                             4.1.2-dfsg-1ubuntu1                    
x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
rc  virtualbox-qt                          4.1.2-dfsg-1ubuntu1                    
x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface 
cute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.<p>
```

Comment: What is the output to `dpkg -l | grep virtual`?

Comment: What is your version of Virtual Box? Where did you install it from: USC or Oracle repository? Did you try - as suggested - to install **virtualbox-dkms** package and `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`?

Comment: As Takkat asked, did you follow the steps on [Download VirtualBox for Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Especially the **Note:** for Ubuntu/Debian users about the *dkms package*?

Comment: @jippie i have updated the question with the result. it was too big to add as comment.

Comment: @Takkat I didn't add oracle repository... just did sudo apt-get install virtualbox. i removed it and tried sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms with no luck. sudo modprobe vboxdrv says "module vboxdrv not found"

Comment: @irrationalJohn i just tried it.

Comment: @irrationalJohn i just tried it.
added deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib to repository.
but I'm getting the following message when I try to update.

W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/oneiric/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Could you check the formatting to dpkg -l in your question? It is a bit messed up right now and I can't figure out completely what it should look like. The lines shouldn't start with `rc`, they should start with `ii`. Installation did not finish as intended.

Comment: After removing the OSE (Ubuntu repository) version try installing Virtual Box from Oracle repository ([see this answer for procedures](http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940)). Virtual Box runs very stable here, just to have said it.

Comment: @jippie updated the formatting. I had copied it from the terminal.

Comment: @Takkat i have done those steps, but for some reason, its not able to check the repository. see the comment above.

Comment: You may have to manually check if the entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` are o.k.. Don't forget to [download and register the public key](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Oh - forgot to mention that: you don't need a sources (deb-src) entry. Just comment out (#...) this line from your sources.list.

Comment: this is what i have @Takkat
'## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib
deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib'

Comment: As said before: try to put a `#` in front of the line `deb-src download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib`. Then `sudo apt-get update`, downlaod the key `wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
`, and install `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.1
`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by

1. Purging Virtualbox:

   `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-ose-qt virtualbox-qt`
2. I then reinstalled;

   `sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-ose virtualbox`

   and noticed:

   ```
   dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-ose:
   virtualbox-ose depends on virtualbox; however:
   Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
   Package virtualbox-4.0 which provides virtualbox is not installed.
   ```
3. so I tried installing virtualbox-4.0;

   `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.0`

   That worked and pulled in the correct VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules.
4. I then had to download and install the correct version of the extension pack `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.16-75491.vbox-extpack`.

That worked, and I now have a fully functioning Virtualbox instance.

Answer (score 17):

Wierdly, for me it worked by closing VirtualBox and then running

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

from the terminal and then restarting VirtualBox

Comment: they key being to close the VirtualBox GUI first.  Thanks @JomanJi!

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much working this comment..............

Comment: Added some extra RAM module and all my VM's got NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005). Looks like sudo modprobe vboxdrv  fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: Just adding a few more words to the previous comment I left in this tread. I have 5 internal drives on my 18.04. One smaller ssd for startup and 4 remaining big ones for everything else. However. None of the .vdi's pointing to the 1st drive where the OS and VBox installation are set up. My setup is that every time my machine is rebooted all remaining 4 drives are enabled on the startup, but not mounted, until I physically start browsing them and mount it. In effect if I run my VBox instance before mounting the drive where my vdi's are pointing, I'll get this funny NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Answer (score 3):

Try to uninstall VirtualBox from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-ose-qt virtualbox-qt
```

If it succesfully uninstalled reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-ose-qt virtualbox-qt
```

Carefully check if the command completes succesfully.

Comment: Install also `dkms`

Comment: `dkms` automatically pulled in as a dependency

Comment: Ok, I usually provide `dkms` also, because I had a strange experience with fedora. But I know, this is ubuntu:)

Comment: is this a problem?

 No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.

Comment: With regard to the initial question, this may very well be related. `Kernal driver not installed`. Did you do a full patch cycle lately? `for a in update upgrade dist-upgrade autoremove; do apt-get -y $a; done`

Comment: @gajdipajti dkms is already there..thanks for the suggestion. i guess as jippie said, it must have been installed as a dependency. I think it has something to do with the no suitable module for running kernal. Unfortunately, even though I have used ubuntu on and off for several years, I am still a noob.

Comment: @jippie I installed ubuntu just 2 days back on this laptop. I did an update after that. I am not able to see any update available. Does it mean I have done a full patch cycle?

Comment: @jippie I am getting the following message when I start virtualbox from terminal 

The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
  Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
  headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

  You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

Comment: You're missing a kernel module, I have no clue why. What is the output for `uname -a` and for `find /lib/modules | grep vboxdrv`?

Comment: uname -a 
 Linux laptop 3.0.0-17-generic-pae #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 17:53:35 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: no thing for find /lib/modules | grep vboxdrv

Comment: vbox insgtall logs 'Uninstalling modules from DKMS
  removing old DKMS module vboxhost version  4.1.12

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.1.12
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.12/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.1.12

DKMS: add Completed.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:172: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.'

Comment: Strange. Your filesystem isn't full, is it? `df -h`

Comment: Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             290G   16G  260G   6% /
udev                  1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 765M  988K  764M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  1.9G  3.5M  1.9G   1% /run/shm

Comment: Don't know. I could advise you lots of things, but I'm afraid I'd just be making your system a mess. Maybe upgrading to 12.04 would solve the issue, but personally I like to wait a couple of weeks to see if any annoying issues pop up with the new release.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting `NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)` whenever I try to start the VM in Debian 9 unstable. None of the solution worked including re-building kernel modules, starting in headless mode etc.

Then I tried to install extension pack and it failed due to `/opt` being not owned by the root! I fixed the ownership of `/opt` and then the pack installed successfully and also virtualbox starts! weird!

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP.
The virtual machine '**Windows XP**' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
```

Then a second window appeared saying I had to run this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

When I Issued that command the following error came out:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                             [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                                                                   [ OK ] 
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                                                              
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.38-16-generic-pae cannot be found at
/lib/modules/2.6.38-16-generic-pae/build or /lib/modules/2.6.38-16-generic-pae/source.
Failed, trying without DKMS
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                    Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong
```

**Solution**

Install the appropriated `linux-headers` for your O.S. version. In my case was:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic-pae
```

Ensure all VirtualBox windows are closed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this : To fix this, run the following, as directed by the prompt:

`sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

If successful, the result will read `Starting VirtualBox kernel modules [ OK ]`
and it's OK now

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but fortunately I solved it not from comand line but from GUI...
open your home directory `~/VirtualBox` VMs
open your hard disk image file
open `name of your virtual machine.vbox`

Your virtual box should run normally from here and that should fix your problem( **if you had the same issue I had , the problem shown up when I had all data in my `VirtualBox.xml` in the .VirtualBox directory was gone!!!)**

Another suggestion: If the previous one didn't work for you ...
go to `.Virtualbox` in you home directory
type the following (`cp VirtualBox.xml-prev VirtualBox.xml`)
I think this should do it for you too...

Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox start
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
```

execute virtualbox :

```
/usr/bin/virtualbox or virtualbox
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to extension pack's different version than other VB packages.

**Fix**

1) Removing extension pack - `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-extension-pack`

2) Disable USB 2 support from VM settings

It will works ! If you want to use extension pack , reinstall the correct version. [You can download it from here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Comment: `pacman` is the package manager for Arch Linux, not Ubuntu. How does this apply to Ubuntu?

Comment: Said command results in `Unable to locate package virtualbox-extension-pack`, downloading the extension pack makes virtualbox say that the same version is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, run the following, as directed by the prompt:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

If successful, the result will read `* Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                   [ OK ]`

If it fails, the reason should be logged in `/var/log/vbox-install.log` but it always seems to be because headers for the current (host) kernel are missing: `Your kernel headers for kernel 3.5.0-22-generic cannot be found` so install them then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) ## e.g. 3.5.0-22-generic
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

**Note:** You will need to do this after every kernel upgrade unless package-maintainers find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run /sbin/vboxconfig as superuser. You may have to wait after some error messages before it completes the command.

Answer (score -2):

Something that seems to not be covered is kernel source. You need the kernel headers for your current kernel installed or it will fail to build the modules needed, resulting in this error.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, could you perhaps include a how-to to help other users that may have this problem?

Answer (score -2):

This is so easy. I had the same problem and I was wondered how easy to solve this is. Make sure to close VirtualBox first, completly. Then issue the following command:

```
sudo vboxreload
```

That's it! I found this out by typing "vbox" and hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice on arch linux. This should also work on Ubuntu and any other distribution.

Comment: Will not work, there is no such command as `vboxreload` on Ubuntu.