# Virtualbox 5.1.8 does not start headless VM

Tags: virtualbox, headless

Recently I installed virtualbox 5.1.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I installed also the extension packs. When I try to start a VM headless I get this error:

```
vboxmanage startvm VM1 --type headless
Waiting for VM "VM1" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'VM1' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

The VM did run fine on virtualbox 5.0. I am connecting by ssh to a remote server so I have no GUI.

Can anyone help me get this work?

Thnx

Comment: Is running properly with "Normal Start" (with the window for console)?

Comment: Nope, it's the same

Comment: It may be [this same issue](http://askubuntu.com/a/223763/260379), check answers 1 and 2

Comment: In GUI it gives more info on the error ... RTR3InintEx failed with rc=-1912

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/a/223763/260379 and http://askubuntu.com/a/685596/260379 solutions

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved from VB 5.0.28 to VB 5.1.8.  My Win 7 virtual machine began random BSD (blue screen).  Nothing I tried over a 3 day period (I am not near a VB expert) failed to prevent the problem from occurring.  I backed out to VB 5.0.28 and the problem went away.

Don't work:   Mint 18 (Trusty)
              VB 5.1.8
              Win7 Virtual Machine

Works:       Mint 18 (Trusty)
             VB 5.0.28
             Win7 Virtual Machine

I can not ID anything other than the VB version as the source.  I would try VB 5.0 to solve the problem.