# Error when starting VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: virtualbox

When I try starting VirtualBox 6.1, it gives me the error "Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object":

[image: Screenshot of error]

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.7 dual booted alongside Chrome OS using crouton.

Comment: what method did you use to install it ?
was it just sudo apt install virtualbox   or did you compile it from source ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox does not run: NS\_ERROR\_FAILURE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217972/virtualbox-does-not-run-ns-error-failure)

Comment: this should fix your issue https://askubuntu.com/a/223763/10676

Answer (score 3):

This can sometimes happen when the host computer does not cleanly shut down a running VirtualBox instance. It can usually be fixed like this:

1. Shut down any VirtualBox VMs that are running
2. Close VirtualBox if it's running
3. Move a configuration file like this:
   `mv ~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml ~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.old`
4. Restart VirtualBox

That should get you running again.

Comment: Thank you! This worked.

Comment: Simple fixes are the best 