# virtualbox not working on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, virtualbox

I'm new to linux please help ,Every time i try to start up virtual box this pops up:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine pc.
The virtual machine 'pc' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
**Component: 
Machine**
Interface: 
IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}

Comment: Did you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/122211/getting-error-message-when-trying-to-start-a-virtual-machine