# VirtualBox error message (rc=-1908) after kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Recently I updated my kernel to `3.2.0-29-generic`. After this, my VirtualBox is not opening and showing up an error message

```
VirtualBox - Error in suplibOsInit
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. 
This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
```

To make it work, I have to execute the following command each time:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

as suggested elsewhere.

It is very annoying. Can anybody help on this? So I can run VirtualBox without needing to execute that command after every boot. I must mention that, I tried several other option suggested in various forums (including reinstalling VirtualVox, DKMS package, etc), but nothing gave me permanent solution.

Comment: What version of Virtual Box? What's the output of `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`?

Comment: Did you do as root `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`? And what version of Virtualbox are you using. all ready been asked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/kernel-driver-not-installed?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You must reinstall the kernel module as requested in the error message.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Make sure you have `dkms` installed and you will not face this problem anymore after kernel upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Comment: false, I'm experiencing this problem and I have dkms installed. Furthermore, there is no /etc/init.d/vboxdrv file in (Ubuntu 12.10 at least)

Comment: I have same problem. there is no vboxdrv in /etc/init.d/.