# Trouble starting virtualbox missing kernel driver

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

I am trying to install Oracle VirtualBox on Ubuntu.

I have installed virtualbox-4.2 from the Oracle website without a hiccup; however, when I create a new windows and try to start it I get the following two error messages.

One says: `Kernel driver not installed(rc=-1908)` and proceeds to tell me to run `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

The other says:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine. The virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
```

I tried `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and discovered that `vboxdrv`
does not exist in the `init.d` directory. I have been trying to install
this for some time without success. I would be very grateful for any help
any one could offer.

Comment: Do you still have the OSE edition from the software centre installed?  If so, remove it before trying to install the PUEL version from the Oracle website.

Comment: Oh, and why would this be off topic?  Installing and running third party applications on Ubuntu is ON-topic.

Comment: I ran a sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-ose before I installed the oracle version.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean this is off topic, I'm new did I post this in the wrong spot?

Comment: Aww yes, I saw that post, but all the answers were based on being able to run sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup, and I do not have vboxdrv in my init.d directory, so the answers on the other problem seemed moot to me.

Comment: @Banner B. schafer : not you, someone else flagged this as off topic.  It might be a duplicate, but it's not off-topic ;-)

Comment: Try the sudo command-you might not be able to see or execute the file unless you use sudo.

Comment: Okay that's working I think I'm now getting an error telling me to check /var/log/vbox-install.log, and that tells me I failed to install dkms and the computer is attempting to install without a makefile:181

Comment: Okay I got it. I don't quite know what happened. Do I close this issue now?