# Virtualbox stopped working in 12.04 LTS after I upgraded kernel using hardware enablement stack

Tags: 12.04, kernel, virtualbox

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) with kernel 3.8 now. Virtualbox fails with this error:

> ```
> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing
>
> '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
>
> as root. Users of Ubuntu, Fedora or Mandriva should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.
> ```

One [proposed solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/229908/36661) I saw was:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

That fails with this message:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualbox-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
Need to get 676 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,899 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe virtualbox-dkms all 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 [676 kB]
Fetched 676 kB in 2s (258 kB/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
(Reading database ... 458635 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (from .../virtualbox-dkms_4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3_all.deb) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-29-generic
Building initial module for 3.8.0-29-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-29-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                 [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                         * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                                      [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) && sudo apt-get install linux-source` . After the installation completes, run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Comment: @NikTh - that does not work. /etc/init.d/vboxdrv does not exist or is not compatible with the kernel version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After applying my solution from https://askubuntu.com/a/342372/36661, the problem came back again after additional system updates (video driver). I chatted with VirtualBox devs on IRC and they told me that Ubuntu does not regularly accept bug fixes from the VirtualBox devs. They recommended that I install the latest VirtualBox package from virtualbox.org, which I did. **That solved the problem.**

The download link for Linux is:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

It is actually a simpler install because you don't need to install guest additions separately.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is found in this comment on the bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1076603/comments/13

Workaround (precise linux-image 3.8.*)

```
wget -O /tmp/virtualbox.patch 'http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=99;filename=vbox-wheezy.patch;att=1;bug=696011'
cd /usr/src/virtualbox-4.1.12/
patch -p4 < /tmp/virtualbox.patch
dkms autoinstall
```

If you don't want to reboot, you may have to run this command:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to go throught a lot before it worked for me, but the last piece was MountainX answer here :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo dkms install virtualbox/4.1.12

sudo wget -O /tmp/virtualbox.patch 'http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=99;filename=vbox-wheezy.patch;att=1;bug=696011'
cd /usr/src/virtualbox-4.1.12/
sudo patch -p4 < /tmp/virtualbox.patch
sudo dkms autoinstall
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

I still had to reboot because of an error with eth0 that had to do with the vboxdrv. But now it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue with a recent kernel upgrade (3.2.0-94-generic) on Ubuntu 12.04 running VirtualBox (4.3.34 r104062) and this worked for me 100%:

```
apt-get --reinstall install dkms
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```