# VirtualBox won't start in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, kernel, virtualbox, permissions, virtualization

I am trying to run VirtualBox so I can install a copy of Windows XP for school. I can get through setting up a new VM but when I try to start it there's a problem with kernels.

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP.
>
> The virtual machine 'Windows XP' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component: Machine
> Interface: IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}

That's the VirtualBox error then there's one that says:

> error in sublibOslnit
>
> kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv.
> Please reinstall the kernel module by executing
>
> `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`
>
> as root. if it is available in your distribution, you should install the dkms package first.

I have ran that and get errors everytime. I dont know how to change the permissions if thats the problem.

Comment: You can [enable root login this way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login), and try re-installation

Comment: Also use `sudo (command)` or `sudo su` and `(command)`. Command in your case is `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 2):

did you get the installation trough the apt-get? i couldn't get any VMs working on virtualbox in ubuntu 12.04, 
i fixed it by removing the virtualbox i installed from the apt-get and installed the version provided on the oracle site, afther that i added myself to the vboxusers group.
this fixed all my problems i had.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to group "vboxusers" is only important to use the usb-drives in a virtualmachine and for some other thinks. 
It´s not neccessary to create a new virtual machine....