# problem with VirtualBox

Tags: 13.04, kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed VirtualBox 4.2.16 on Ubuntu and I want to create a virtual disk but when I create a virtual disk by click on Start button, the error message appears

---

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

---

DKMS is installed
and Kernel headers version is 3.11.2-031102-generic

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried re-installing dkms as suggested [in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/229908)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Download a different version. Ubuntu i386, because I had this problem and it was because I was trying to use 64 bit version, and virtual box doesn't support it.