# Cannot start virtualbox VM's: Kernel driver is not installed

Tags: virtualbox

I'm a Linux Novice

Was running 12.04 with virtualbox 4.2.  Everything was rosie.

Upgraded to 12.10; now Virtualbox will run, but can start any VM's.  Get error 'kernel driver not installed'  I've ran /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup but get error 'Your kernel headers for kernel 3.8.0-32-generic cannot be found'

I tried running apt-get linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic but get error 'Pakcage linux-headers-3.8.0.32-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package'.

uname -r responds with 3.8.0-32-generic

ls /usr/src contains linux-headers-3.5.0-42; linux-headers-3.5.0-42-generic & vboxhost-4.3.0

How do I resolve this? I now understand I should have installed DKMS before performing the OS upgrade and kernel headers would have been updated.

Comment: Search for a file called "vboxdrv.ko". In the same folder there are some other libraries as well. Try to manually load them into the kernel by using "sudo insmod <libfile>". To search for a file use "find / -name <filename>". If that's the cause of your problem it can easily fixed by adding those libs into the kernel during boot.

Comment: When I run sudo insmod vboxdrv.ko but it fails with -1 Invalid module format

Comment: I tried running apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) but that fails with error message 'Package linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.  E: Package 'linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic' has no installation candidate'

Comment: Sorry but then I cannot help on this other then suggest to try re-installing virtualbox. It seems that the modules do not fit the kernel ... but thats a wild guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Install all kernel package include `kernel-header`, with a newest kernel (3.11.0-13 (binary) with synaptic. Then reboot . The system will start with new kernel and ... work. (my problem is using vmware)

If you have a problem with 3.5.0-42 you can start with old one.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time this is the fix for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo reboot
```

If that fails try:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo reboot
```

Don’t worry you will not lose any of your created virtual machines.