# Trying to create a win7 virtual box

Tags: 12.04, drivers, virtualbox

But this happens:

[image: Edit item description here]

Would anyone know what to do, I do not know too very much about terminal, so please be patient. Running Ubuntu 12.04 64x AMD.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and (as it says in the error message) run `sudo service vboxdrv setup`.

The reason you see this error is because the kernel was recently upgraded, but the VirtualBox driver was built for the older kernel (which you are no longer running). Normally, dkms automatically recompiles any modules for newer kernels, so you don't have to do it, but (like me) it's not happening. Make sure dkms is installed (`sudo apt-get install dkms`).

Comment: tried to run `sudo service vboxdrv setup` but got `vboxdrv: unrecognised service` 

Screenshot from terminal: http://imgur.com/rhCV4Hj

Comment: It seems you have the version that is in the main Ubuntu repos. In that case, follow the solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/229908/241580).

Comment: `no suitable module for running kernel found` after `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms` should i continue with `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` anyways?

Comment: No. You need to install the headers for the current version. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`. This will also automatically install headers for future kernels.

Comment: Dont think it worked, http://imgur.com/nqPJ5vI

Comment: Well, that just backfired on me. Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-$(uname -r)`

Comment: No, that should be a literal `uname -r`. What `uname -r` does is print the kernel version that you are currently running. You can test this by running the command separately.

Comment: `couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-generic-3.8.0-35-generic'`

Comment: My bad. Get rid of the first generic, so that your final command looks like `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Comment: that looks as if that works, now move on to `sudo modprobe vboxdrv
`?

Comment: Yes. That shouldn't return any error. The second command might return an error, but you can ignore that.

Comment: First command: `FATAL: Module Vboxdrv not found.`

Comment: Lowercase `vboxdrv`?

Comment: yeah, lower, sorry