# What do I need to do to get VirtualBox with dkms installed?

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install VirtualBox 4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit via apt along with the `dkms` package, but the VirtualBox kernel fails to get installed.

What do I need to do to get VirtualBox with dkms installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions at the Oracle website to get the latest version of Virtual box, and found it to install quite well:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

I added this line to my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

I did need to download the extension pack separately, and install it within Virtualbox - I understand this is normal behavior.  Then I also needed to add myself to the Virtualbox user group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers my-user-name
```

Comment: Charles, I exactly did the same lines. Sorry I am not getting this line "virtualbox-4.3"
E: Package 'virtualbox-4.3' has no installation candidate
root@sanvi:/home/kiran#

Comment: Very strange - and you added the fill line to the end of your /etc/apt/sources.list?