# Trying to install older virtualbox version on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I was trying to install a old version of virtualbox (4.3.0) because I will work in a project that use it.

After I installed the VirtualBox I got this error when I write `virtualbox --version`:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.8.0-36-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "S&tart" under id 16 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Pause" under id 17 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Reset" under id 18 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "D&iscard saved state..." under id 24 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Re&fresh..." under id 25 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Show in File Manager" under id 27 
Qt WARNING: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Create Shortcut on Desktop" under id 28
```

If I run this code as the warning says:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

I got other error:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-4.3.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/make.log for more information.
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

I tried to resolve my problem with these other askubuntu questions without success:

[How do I fix a vboxdrv setup failure in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506405/how-do-i-fix-a-vboxdrv-setup-failure-in-virtualbox)

[Virtualbox error after installing new linux kernel 4.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724127/virtualbox-error-after-installing-new-linux-kernel-4-4)

[Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

I need this VB version because I'm using vagrant 1.7.2, and when I run `vagrant up` I got this:

```
VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

so, I'm not able to go up the virtualbox in ubuntu 16.

Edit: I added the log from `/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for vboxhost-4.3.40 for kernel 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
dom mar  5 09:44:42 VET 2017
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mpnotification-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/process-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semevent-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semeventmulti-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semfastmutex-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semmutex-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/spinlock-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/thread-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/thread2-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/threadctxhooks-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/time-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/timer-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/timer-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtTimerLnxStartSubTimer’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/timer-r0drv-linux.c:364:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘mod_timer_pinned’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
             mod_timer_pinned(&pSubTimer->u.Std.LnxTimer, pSubTimer->u.Std.ulNextJiffies);
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/timer-r0drv-linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/timer-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:440: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.40/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out with the problem, but with a solution that is not 100% correct for me, but let me back to work.

First, the ubuntu's lasted version does not compatible with Virtualbox < 5.0, after some version are released, the older are deprecated, so it's a big problem for me because Vagrant 1.7.2 doesn't work with > 5.0. Update the Vagrant is not an option for me, because whole the setup was created to work with Vagrant 1.7.2.

After I tested a lot of differents way to repair this error, is "almost imposible", the only way that I could do, is install a older ubuntu version (14.04) that has the correct kernel version that made all this problem and let Virtualbox works. So I installed ubuntu 14.04. run `vagrant up` and every works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the current stable version of Virtualbox available here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Virtualbox can import and export any OVF/OVA files created by other versions of Virtualbox.

Import Details:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import

Export Details:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-export

Comment: This solution did not work for me, for this following reasons: 1.- I need to use vagrant 1.7.2 Strictly, and it is not support for VB version 4.5+. So If I install a recent version of VB my vagrant up won't run, I will get an error "No usable default provider could be found for your system." 2.- If I install vagrant 1.7.3 that I can use with VB 5.0 when I run vagrant up, vagrant up will be broken and will show other error.