# Can't install virtualbox on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox

I simply couldn't install virtualbox on Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 5.4.0-90-generic). Trying different versions from 5.2 to 6.1 and always have the same error when requested `/sbin/vboxconfig`:

`vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.`

I have tried all approaches mentioned out there, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506405/how-do-i-fix-a-vboxdrv-setup-failure-in-virtualbox), [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126591/virtualbox-error-after-last-ubuntu-software-update), [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900118/vboxdrv-sh-failed-modprobe-vboxdrv-failed-please-use-dmesg-to-find-out-why) (already had UEFI secure boot disabled), none of them works.

It's getting really frustrating. Anyone got some ideas?

Comment: What is content of the file /var/log/vbox-setup.log ?

Comment: @pasmanpasmański It's a pretty long file, and this is one of the errors `./arch/x86/include/asm/tlbflush.h: In function ‘__native_flush_tlb’:
././include/linux/compiler_types.h:214:24: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘__inline’
 #define asm_inline asm __inline
`

Comment: @EternaL You probably has too old gcc. Best is to install newer release of Ubuntu, 20.04LTS or 21.10 (only 9 month support)

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Good point, I upgraded to gcc 9 and the error went away. Thanks a lot.