# How can I start VirtualBox in the face of a DKMS error?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I'm trying to restart my virtual machine (Oracle VM VirtualBox) with a Windows OS on it from Ubuntu 14.04 after having upgraded from 12.04.

Whenever I try to start the VM session, I get two error dialog boxes:

(1)

> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component:  Machine
>   Interface:  IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}

(2)

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or
>   there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the
>   kernel module by executing
>
> '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'
>
> as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install
>   the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel
>   changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

Based upon the suggestion of error box 2, I then run the following:

```
user@user][user] sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup            [..]
[sudo] password for user]: 
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                       [ OK ] 
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                  Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/make.log for more information.

 * Failed, trying without DKMS
 * Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                        
 * Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong
```

I have tried to vorrect for this by installing dkms, bbswitch-dkms, open-vm-dkms and open-vm-tools-dkms packages but this doesn't work.

**EDIT**:
The log files in response to comment below state:

```
DKMS make.log for vboxhost-4.1.18 for kernel 3.13.0-40-generic
(x86_64) Wed Dec  3 21:14:39 GMT 2014 make: Entering directory
`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic'   LD     
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/built-in.o   LD     
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o   CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In
function ‘vboxdrvLinuxUid’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:226:5:
error: incompatible types when returning type ‘kuid_t’ but ‘RTUID’ was
expected
     return current->cred->uid;
     ^ /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In
function ‘vboxdrvLinuxGid’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:235:5:
error: incompatible types when returning type ‘kgid_t’ but ‘RTGID’ was
expected
     return current->cred->gid;
     ^ /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In
function ‘vboxdrvLinuxEuid’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:244:5:
error: incompatible types when returning type ‘kuid_t’ but ‘RTUID’ was
expected
     return current->cred->euid;
     ^ /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:248:1:
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]  } 
^ /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In
function ‘vboxdrvLinuxUid’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:230:1:
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]  } 
^ /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In
function ‘vboxdrvLinuxGid’:
/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:239:1:
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]  } 
^ make[2]: ***
[/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o]
Error 1 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/vboxdrv]
Error 2 make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build] Error
2 make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic'
```

Comment: Perhaps check the log file it says to, which gives more information on what happened during the compile?  `/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.18/build/make.log` is the path it states.

Comment: You may have one or two problems here: outdated virtualbox and possibly the wrong compiler. What is the result of `sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep '^cc '`? If it's gcc-4.8, you could try to build with gcc-4.6 by using `sudo update-alternatives --config cc`, selecting gcc-4.6 as the default, and trying to the`vboxdrv setup` command again. Otherwise, you may just try updating VirtualBox to the newest version (4.3) which may fix the problem.

Comment: The output from running that command is `cc auto     /usr/bin/gcc`. How do I know what version of gcc is being used?

Comment: just follow the softlink. `ll /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

This is a kernel/driver issue.  It's the same under xen with xcp so not limited to virtualbox  The blktap driver fails to compile on 3.13 kernels.

This might work:

wget http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blktap-dkms/blktap-dkms_2.0.93-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

```
dpkg -i  blktap-dkms_2.0.93-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 115884 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace blktap-dkms 2.0.91-1ubuntu1 
(using blktap-dkms_2.0.93-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 2.0.91
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking replacement blktap-dkms ...
Setting up blktap-dkms (2.0.93-0ubuntu4) ...
Loading new blktap-2.0.93 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-40-generic
Building initial module for 3.13.0-40-generic
Done.

blktap:
Running module version sanity check.
  - Original module
  - No original module exists within this kernel
  - Installation
  - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install completed.
```

You basically just use the version that comes with trusty tahr