# Ubuntu kernel not upgrading with upgrade to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 15.04, 15.10

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit to Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. I read that 15.10 was using the 4.1 or 4.2 kernel, but I noticed that my kernel didn't upgrade.

When I type in the terminal `uname -r`, I get `3.19.0-18-generic`

Same thing in GRUB: the only kernel I can choose is `3.19.0-18`

Can someone explain how to upgrade the kernel?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bug in the distribution upgrade script.

You can install the correct kernel by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

After a reboot you should have the 4.2 kernel.

Comment: I'm installing it right now.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I now have the `4.2.0-16` kernel.

Comment: You know what's funny about this?  I encountered this bug, so I reported it as a bug, and Ubuntu devs are telling me that this bug does not exist.  Mind you, I've encountered this bug on two upgrades and one OS install over an existing broken OS.  In all three cases, I ended up having to manually install the kernel like this.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1510137

Comment: Interestingly, this didn't work for me. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64) which I upgraded from 15.04. When I launch the command `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` it returns that I'm running the latest version. This VM is hosted at DigitialOcean, could their cache be my issue?

Comment: You need to change kernel from VPS menu. It is unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

There are two bugs here, one in software-properties https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1506169 and one in the ubuntu upgrade process https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1509305. Both of these are being fixed and should be resolved shortly.

As mentioned installing linux-generic before or after the upgrade will ensure you have the new version of the kernel installed.

The version of release upgrader in -proposed will now (2015-10-28) do the right thing, you can use it via adding the "--proposed" switch to do-release-upgrade or check-new-release-gtk. Alternatively, if you wait a couple of hours the fix will move to updates and will just work.