# Can't install Ubuntu 15.10 on virtualbox 5.0.0

Tags: graphics, ati, virtualbox, kubuntu

[image]

As you can see in the gif picture I can't install Ubuntu on virtualbox.
Whenever I move my mouse, the screen will change dramatically.

Actually, I don't know what keyword should I use, if I want to find a solution with Google. It seemed to be display problem, but how can I fix it?

Ubuntu 15.10, Kubuntu 15.04 and Kubuntu 15.10 all couldn't install.

My virtualbox version: 5.0.0 r101573
VM Ram: 4096 MB
Video Memory: 12 or 128 (in gif, it's 12)
I didn't enable 3D acceleration.
CPU cores: 4
Other settings were default.

Host information:
CPU: Xeon v3-1231
RAM: 8G
OS: Win 8.1
Graphic card: AMD R9-270 (MSI)

Comment: Thanks you Takkat. I don't know that there is a new version of virtualbox. I updated it and all the problems were gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing a new release of Ubuntu it may on occasion be that the application version of Virtual Box was not yet able to fully adapt to all changes our new release may have made. Most critical are kernel upgrades that need additional tweaks in VirtualBox to get them running.

When browsing the [changelogs from Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) we can see a lot of bugfixes on each version which often also fix bugs that appeared on any new Ubuntu release. At present we can see that e.g. bugs for kernel 4.2. (installed with 15.10) were only fixed from release >= 5.0.2.

- It is usually helpful to [upgrade Virtual Box to the newest stable version](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) when installing a new distribution release. We should also not forget to update our Guest Additions.
- If that did not resolve the issues it also helps to upgrade the guest Ubuntu for bugfixes. If we can not boot to a graphical interface this can also be done from a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell):

  ```
  apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Graphics issues that could not be resolved by the steps above may need an updated graphics driver on the host.

Comment: Another problem that popped up on my upgrade to 15.10 was that the kernel wasn't being updated.  So while I could install Virtual Box it didn't have /dev/vbox which was solved by http://askubuntu.com/questions/689358/ubuntu-kernel-not-updating-with-15-10/694459