# Kernel not upgraded to 4.2.x

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit to Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit but noticed that my kernel didn't upgrade and still shows: .

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-35-generic
```

So I tried the following command to upgrade it to 4.2 kernel but it says the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic
[sudo] password for xxxxxxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

EDIT:

Also to add that issuing a `dpkg --list 'linux-headers*' 'linux-image*'`
shows that I may have a `4.2.0-16 kernel` somewhere . But the `uname` still shows that

`Linux 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
$ dpkg --list 'linux-headers*' 'linux-image*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                               Version                        Architecture                   Description
+++-==================================================-==============================-==============================-==========================================================================================================
un  linux-headers                                      <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)
un  linux-headers-3.0                                  <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-24                            3.13.0-24.47                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic                    3.13.0-24.47                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-35                            3.13.0-35.62                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic                    3.13.0-35.62                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-36                            3.13.0-36.63                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic                    3.13.0-36.63                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-43                            3.13.0-43.72                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic                    3.13.0-43.72                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                    
un  linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
un  linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-48                            3.13.0-48.80                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0                                                          
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic                    3.13.0-48.80                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                    
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-52                            3.13.0-52.86                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0                                                          
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic                    3.13.0-52.86                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                    
un  linux-headers-3.13.0-62-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
un  linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-44                            3.16.0-44.59                   all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0                                                          
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic                    3.16.0-44.59                   amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                    
un  linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
un  linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
un  linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
un  linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
ii  linux-headers-4.2.0-16                             4.2.0-16.19                    all                            Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.2.0                                                           
ii  linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic                     4.2.0-16.19                    amd64                          Linux kernel headers for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                     
ii  linux-headers-generic                              4.2.0.16.18                    amd64                          Generic Linux kernel headers                                                                                 
un  linux-image                                        <none>**                         <none>                         (no description available)                                                                                   
un  linux-image-3.0                                    <none>                         <none>                         (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                      3.13.0-24.47                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic                      3.13.0-35.62                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic                      3.13.0-36.63                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic                      3.13.0-43.72                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic                      3.13.0-45.74                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic                      3.13.0-46.79                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic                      3.13.0-48.80                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic                      3.13.0-52.86                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic                      3.13.0-62.102                  amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic                      3.13.0-63.103                  amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-44-generic                      3.16.0-44.59                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic                      3.19.0-26.28                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic                      3.19.0-28.30                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic                      3.19.0-30.34                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic                      3.19.0-31.36                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic                       4.2.0-16.19                    amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                3.13.0-24.47                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic                3.13.0-35.62                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic                3.13.0-36.63                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic                3.13.0-43.72                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic                3.13.0-45.74                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic                3.13.0-46.79                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic                3.13.0-48.80                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic                3.13.0-52.86                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic                3.13.0-62.102                  amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic                3.13.0-63.103                  amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-44-generic                3.16.0-44.59                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-26-generic                3.19.0-26.28                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic                3.19.0-28.30                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic                3.19.0-30.34                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic                3.19.0-31.36                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic                 4.2.0-16.19                    amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                4.2.0.16.18                    amd64                          Generic Linux kernel image
```

I have also done a `sudo update-grub`. But even after that the `grub.cfg` looks like this:

```
$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry                                                                set prev_saved_entry=                                                          save_env prev_saved_entry                                                           set boot_once=true                                                       fi                                                                       function savedefault {                                                                          if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then                                                                 saved_entry="${chosen}"                                                      save_env saved_entry                                                          fi                                                                   }                                                                        function recordfail {                                                                          set recordfail=1                                                               if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi                                                                   }                                                                        function load_video {                                                                          if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then                                                                         insmod all_video                                                                  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_IN
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
#set_background_image "images/tile.png";

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
                set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
        else
                set vt_handoff=
        fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-C80C8C860C8C716C' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  C80C8C860C8C716C
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C80C8C860C8C716C
        fi
        parttool ${root} hidden-
        chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/33_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID=727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
}
submenu "Advanced options for Ubuntu"{
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-35-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-35-generic-advanced-727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos6'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-35-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID=727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-35-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-35-generic-recovery-727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos6'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-35-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID=727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5 ro recovery nomodeset 
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos6'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos6'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5 ro recovery nomodeset 
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/33_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/34_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/34_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
        fi
        knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 727baaef-c176-43eb-adce-e531d02064c5
        fi
        linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/35_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/36_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/36_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Here is the output:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10 
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu kernel not updating with 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689358/ubuntu-kernel-not-updating-with-15-10)

Comment: Note the question here uses the same command as in the accepted answer. This may not be duplicate.

Comment: It looks like you did not upgrade the system proprely. Please add output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`.

Comment: @Oli I noticed that. That may be either not a real upgrade or some problem with `sources.list`.

Comment: And also it looks weird that 15.04 had 3.13 kernel.

Comment: Is the result the same after a reboot?

Comment: Here is the output:  cat /etc/lsb-release: $ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"

Comment: Kernel 4.x is installed. Perhaps you should start into Grub, select boot your 4.x kernel and uninstall the 3.x kernels after that.

Comment: @A.B. Unfortunately no option of selecting the 4.2 kernel is coming in the Grub menu. It only shows the 3.x kernels. - P.D.

Comment: Can someone help please?

Comment: @Prana Can you try `apt-get autoclean  && apt-get autoremove`, followed by grub configuration. autoclean and autoremove should cleanup old kernel versions. If this works, let me know.