# How to install virtual box kernel?

Tags: virtualbox

I am not new to Virtualbox, having used it many times on Windows.

I had recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my main pc, and I want to install Windows XP so I can run some Windows applications within Ubuntu. (I would dual boot, but that's a long story.)

Every time I start the virtual machine, I get the errors shown in the picture, and I can't figure out how to solve them.

[image: Error I received]

Comment: Most likely duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed. Try it and let us know if it fixed the issue.