# Vagrant ssh (terminal freezes)

Tags: server, php, 15.10, virtualization, vagrant

I have virtual machine with vagrant and ansible, when i connect to virtual machine  with vagrant ssh, the terminal always freezes if i don't type something, the terminal is freezed. I can't type anything, and like that all over again. Please help!

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem was 2 virtual machines running in the same time. You can check if you have 2 machines running with `vagrant global-status`. That causes terminal when in ssh to freeze.

**New Update:**

If you still have problems [install Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/).

*If you still experience the same thing, then reinstall  virtual box, this happens when you install [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed) (virtual box kernel) if you installed this reinstall virtual box and everything will be fine.*

**Or if you are lazy to read just execute this commands**

Re-install virtualbox-dkms package first

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms

sudo modprobe vboxdrv
sudo modprobe vboxnetflt
```

**After all this steps if you still have freeze when vagrant ssh do this:**
Enter in your vagrant folder and remove vagrant box with the following command

```
vagrant box remove ubuntu/trusty64
```

*P.S Name of my vagrant box is ubuntu/trusty64 , yours can be different, to see the list of the boxes in your VM type following command*

```
vagrant box list
```

Comment: I have this problem but running a single VM is not an option for me - any other ideas?

Comment: yes i do...  I experienced that problem, install ruby

Comment: let me know if this helps

Comment: Ruby is already installed. I've added an answer.

Comment: Finally working now after increasing memory value

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem seemed to occur due to one or a combination of:

- Compression on the SSH session
- An SSH tunnel running at the same time

Most likely the SSH tunnel - I was tunneling X to allow access to a web browser. I think this perhaps in combination with the compression was causing the session to lock up.