# Virtualbox error after installing new linux kernel 4.4

Tags: virtualbox

I have ubuntu x64 15.04 and I have installed latest stable kernel 4.4.
I also installed `virtualbox 5.0.14`, downloaded from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

I tried to run a virtual machine and I got this error:
[image]

I tried to run: `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup` and I got: `Bad argument setup`
so I tried `sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup` and I got:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modulesError! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
 ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! DKMS tree already contains: vboxhost-5.0.14
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

and here is the `vbox-install.log`: http://pastebin.com/raw/2u2zcS75

How can I solve it? I'd like to keep the new kernel.

Thanks

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the kernel. I have the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 on `3.16.0-59-generic` kernel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 3):

Try to install g++/gcc version 5.3 and compile dkms with it

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I was able to run virtual machine using the following advice

First try

`sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.4.0-040400-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-040400-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/5.0.14/build/make.log for more information.
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

add repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

install gcc/g++

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
```

The next step is to add alternatives to gcc/g++
show installed versions

```
ls -lh /usr/bin/gcc*
```

and for each of them add alternative, mine are

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 20 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```

last step is to select what to use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

and select 3 entry in my case

Now try to compile DKMS

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Now it is successfully compiled

`sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
```

Comment: It changed something but did not solve the problem completely. I guess you have packages installed I missed.

Comment: I now fixed it by installing VirtualBox from the website not from Ubuntu sources!

Answer (score 0):

Reverting the `/sbin/rcvboxdrv` to the old version fixes the issue. In case the old version of the file is no longer available to you, here is the copy:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Oracle VM VirtualBox
# Linux kernel module init script

#
# Copyright (C) 2006-2015 Oracle Corporation
#
# This file is part of VirtualBox Open Source Edition (OSE), as
# available from http://www.virtualbox.org. This file is free software;
# you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU
# General Public License (GPL) as published by the Free Software
# Foundation, in version 2 as it comes in the "COPYING" file of the
# VirtualBox OSE distribution. VirtualBox OSE is distributed in the
# hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY of any kind.
#

# chkconfig: 345 20 80
# description: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       vboxdrv
# Required-Start: $syslog
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH
DEVICE=/dev/vboxdrv
LOG="/var/log/vbox-install.log"
VERSION=5.0.12
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe

if $MODPROBE -c | grep -q '^allow_unsupported_modules  *0'; then
  MODPROBE="$MODPROBE --allow-unsupported-modules"
fi

[ -f /etc/debian_release -a -f /lib/lsb/init-functions ] || NOLSB=yes
[ -f /etc/vbox/vbox.cfg ] && . /etc/vbox/vbox.cfg
export BUILD_TYPE
export USERNAME
export USER=$USERNAME

if [ -n "$INSTALL_DIR" ]; then
    VBOXMANAGE="$INSTALL_DIR/VBoxManage"
    MODULE_SRC="$INSTALL_DIR/src/vboxhost"
else
    VBOXMANAGE="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage"
    MODULE_SRC="/usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost"
fi
BUILDINTMP="$MODULE_SRC/build_in_tmp"
DODKMS="$MODULE_SRC/do_dkms"

# silently exit if the package was uninstalled but not purged,
# applies to Debian packages only (but shouldn't hurt elsewhere)
[ ! -f /etc/debian_release -o -x $VBOXMANAGE -a -x $BUILDINTMP ] || exit 0

if [ -n "$NOLSB" ]; then
    if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
        system=redhat
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
        system=suse
    elif [ -f /etc/gentoo-release ]; then
        system=gentoo
    fi
fi

[ -r /etc/default/virtualbox ] && . /etc/default/virtualbox

if [ -z "$NOLSB" ]; then
    . /lib/lsb/init-functions
    fail_msg() {
        echo ""
        log_failure_msg "$1"
    }
    succ_msg() {
        log_end_msg 0
    }
    begin_msg() {
        log_daemon_msg "$@"
    }
else
    if [ "$system" = "redhat" ]; then
        . /etc/init.d/functions
        fail_msg() {
            echo -n " "
            echo_failure
            echo
            echo "  ($1)"
        }
        succ_msg() {
            echo -n " "
            echo_success
            echo
        }
    elif [ "$system" = "suse" ]; then
        . /etc/rc.status
        fail_msg() {
            rc_failed 1
            rc_status -v
            echo "  ($1)"
        }
        succ_msg() {
            rc_reset
            rc_status -v
        }
    elif [ "$system" = "gentoo" ]; then
        if [ -f /sbin/functions.sh ]; then
            . /sbin/functions.sh
        elif [ -f /etc/init.d/functions.sh ]; then
            . /etc/init.d/functions.sh
        fi
        fail_msg() {
            eerror "$1"
        }
        succ_msg() {
            eend "$?"
        }
        begin_msg() {
            ebegin "$1"
        }
        if [ "`which $0`" = "/sbin/rc" ]; then
            shift
        fi
    else
        fail_msg() {
            echo " ...failed!"
            echo "  ($1)"
        }
        succ_msg() {
            echo " ...done."
        }
    fi
    if [ "$system" != "gentoo" ]; then
        begin_msg() {
            [ -z "${1:-}" ] && return 1
            if [ -z "${2:-}" ]; then
                echo -n "$1"
            else
                echo -n "$1: $2"
            fi
        }
    fi
fi

failure()
{
    fail_msg "$1"
    exit 0
}

running()
{
    lsmod | grep -q "$1[^_-]"
}

start()
{
    begin_msg "Starting VirtualBox kernel modules"
    if [ -d /proc/xen ]; then
        failure "Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported"
    fi
    if ! running vboxdrv; then
        if ! rm -f $DEVICE; then
            failure "Cannot remove $DEVICE"
        fi
        if ! $MODPROBE vboxdrv > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            failure "modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why"
        fi
        sleep .2
    fi
    # ensure the character special exists
    if [ ! -c $DEVICE ]; then
        MAJOR=`sed -n 's;\([0-9]\+\) vboxdrv$;\1;p' /proc/devices`
        if [ ! -z "$MAJOR" ]; then
            MINOR=0
        else
            MINOR=`sed -n 's;\([0-9]\+\) vboxdrv$;\1;p' /proc/misc`
            if [ ! -z "$MINOR" ]; then
                MAJOR=10
            fi
        fi
        if [ -z "$MAJOR" ]; then
            rmmod vboxdrv 2>/dev/null
            failure "Cannot locate the VirtualBox device"
        fi
        if ! mknod -m 0660 $DEVICE c $MAJOR $MINOR 2>/dev/null; then
            rmmod vboxdrv 2>/dev/null
            failure "Cannot create device $DEVICE with major $MAJOR and minor $MINOR"
        fi
    fi
    # ensure permissions
    if ! chown :root $DEVICE 2>/dev/null; then
        rmmod vboxpci 2>/dev/null
        rmmod vboxnetadp 2>/dev/null
        rmmod vboxnetflt 2>/dev/null
        rmmod vboxdrv 2>/dev/null
        failure "Cannot change group root for device $DEVICE"
    fi
    if ! $MODPROBE vboxnetflt > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        failure "modprobe vboxnetflt failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why"
    fi
    if ! $MODPROBE vboxnetadp > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        failure "modprobe vboxnetadp failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why"
    fi
    if ! $MODPROBE vboxpci > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        failure "modprobe vboxpci failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why"
    fi
    # Create the /dev/vboxusb directory if the host supports that method
    # of USB access.  The USB code checks for the existance of that path.
    if grep -q usb_device /proc/devices; then
        mkdir -p -m 0750 /dev/vboxusb 2>/dev/null
        chown root:vboxusers /dev/vboxusb 2>/dev/null
    fi
    succ_msg
}

stop()
{
    begin_msg "Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules"
    if running vboxpci; then
        if ! rmmod vboxpci 2>/dev/null; then
            failure "Cannot unload module vboxpci"
        fi
    fi
    if running vboxnetadp; then
        if ! rmmod vboxnetadp 2>/dev/null; then
            failure "Cannot unload module vboxnetadp"
        fi
    fi
    if running vboxdrv; then
        if running vboxnetflt; then
            if ! rmmod vboxnetflt 2>/dev/null; then
                failure "Cannot unload module vboxnetflt"
            fi
        fi
        if ! rmmod vboxdrv 2>/dev/null; then
            failure "Cannot unload module vboxdrv"
        fi
        if ! rm -f $DEVICE; then
            failure "Cannot unlink $DEVICE"
        fi
    fi
    succ_msg
}

# enter the following variables in /etc/default/virtualbox:
#   SHUTDOWN_USERS="foo bar"  
#     check for running VMs of user foo and user bar
#   SHUTDOWN=poweroff
#   SHUTDOWN=acpibutton
#   SHUTDOWN=savestate
#     select one of these shutdown methods for running VMs
stop_vms()
{
    wait=0
    for i in $SHUTDOWN_USERS; do
        # don't create the ipcd directory with wrong permissions!
        if [ -d /tmp/.vbox-$i-ipc ]; then
            export VBOX_IPC_SOCKETID="$i"
            VMS=`$VBOXMANAGE --nologo list runningvms | sed -e 's/^".*".*{\(.*\)}/\1/' 2>/dev/null`
            if [ -n "$VMS" ]; then
                if [ "$SHUTDOWN" = "poweroff" ]; then
                    begin_msg "Powering off remaining VMs"
                    for v in $VMS; do
                        $VBOXMANAGE --nologo controlvm $v poweroff
                    done
                    succ_msg
                elif [ "$SHUTDOWN" = "acpibutton" ]; then
                    begin_msg "Sending ACPI power button event to remaining VMs"
                    for v in $VMS; do
                        $VBOXMANAGE --nologo controlvm $v acpipowerbutton
                        wait=30
                    done
                    succ_msg
                elif [ "$SHUTDOWN" = "savestate" ]; then
                    begin_msg "Saving state of remaining VMs"
                    for v in $VMS; do
                        $VBOXMANAGE --nologo controlvm $v savestate
                    done
                    succ_msg
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
    # wait for some seconds when doing ACPI shutdown
    if [ "$wait" -ne 0 ]; then
        begin_msg "Waiting for $wait seconds for VM shutdown"
        sleep $wait
        succ_msg
    fi
}

# setup_script
setup()
{
    stop
    DKMS=`which dkms 2>/dev/null`
    if [ -n "$DKMS" ]; then
      begin_msg "Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules"
      $DODKMS uninstall vboxhost vboxdrv vboxnetflt vboxnetadp > $LOG
      succ_msg
    fi
    if find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxpci\.*" 2>/dev/null|grep -q vboxpci; then
        begin_msg "Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module"
        find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxpci\.*" 2>/dev/null|xargs rm -f 2>/dev/null
        succ_msg
    fi  
    if find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxnetadp\.*" 2>/dev/null|grep -q vboxnetadp; then
        begin_msg "Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module"
        find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxnetadp\.*" 2>/dev/null|xargs rm -f 2>/dev/null
        succ_msg
    fi  
    if find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxnetflt\.*" 2>/dev/null|grep -q vboxnetflt; then
        begin_msg "Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module"
        find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxnetflt\.*" 2>/dev/null|xargs rm -f 2>/dev/null
        succ_msg
    fi  
    if find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxdrv\.*" 2>/dev/null|grep -q vboxdrv; then
        begin_msg "Removing old VirtualBox kernel module"
        find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name "vboxdrv\.*" 2>/dev/null|xargs rm -f 2>/dev/null
        succ_msg
    fi
    if [ -n "$DKMS" ]; then
      begin_msg "Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS"
      if ! $DODKMS install vboxhost $VERSION >> $LOG; then
        fail_msg "Failed, trying without DKMS"
        DKMS=""
      fi
    fi
    if [ -z "$DKMS" ]; then
      begin_msg "Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules"
      if ! $BUILDINTMP \
          --save-module-symvers /tmp/vboxdrv-Module.symvers \
          --module-source "$MODULE_SRC/vboxdrv" \
          --no-print-directory install >> $LOG 2>&1; then
          failure "Look at $LOG to find out what went wrong"
      fi
      if ! $BUILDINTMP \
          --use-module-symvers /tmp/vboxdrv-Module.symvers \
          --module-source "$MODULE_SRC/vboxnetflt" \
          --no-print-directory install >> $LOG 2>&1; then
          failure "Look at $LOG to find out what went wrong"
      fi
      if ! $BUILDINTMP \
          --use-module-symvers /tmp/vboxdrv-Module.symvers \
          --module-source "$MODULE_SRC/vboxnetadp" \
          --no-print-directory install >> $LOG 2>&1; then
          failure "Look at $LOG to find out what went wrong"
      fi
      if ! $BUILDINTMP \
          --use-module-symvers /tmp/vboxdrv-Module.symvers \
          --module-source "$MODULE_SRC/vboxpci" \
          --no-print-directory install >> $LOG 2>&1; then
          failure "Look at $LOG to find out what went wrong"
      fi
    fi
    rm -f /etc/vbox/module_not_compiled
    succ_msg
    start
}

dmnstatus()
{
    if running vboxdrv; then
        str="vboxdrv"
        if running vboxnetflt; then
            str="$str, vboxnetflt"
            if running vboxnetadp; then
                str="$str, vboxnetadp"
            fi
        fi
        if running vboxpci; then
            str="$str, vboxpci"
        fi
        echo "VirtualBox kernel modules ($str) are loaded."
        for i in $SHUTDOWN_USERS; do
            # don't create the ipcd directory with wrong permissions!
            if [ -d /tmp/.vbox-$i-ipc ]; then
                export VBOX_IPC_SOCKETID="$i"
                VMS=`$VBOXMANAGE --nologo list runningvms | sed -e 's/^".*".*{\(.*\)}/\1/' 2>/dev/null`
                if [ -n "$VMS" ]; then
                    echo "The following VMs are currently running:"
                    for v in $VMS; do
                       echo "  $v"
                    done
                fi
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "VirtualBox kernel module is not loaded."
    fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop_vms
    stop
    ;;
stop_vms)
    stop_vms
    ;;
restart)
    stop && start
    ;;
force-reload)
    stop
    start
    ;;
setup)
    setup
    ;;
status)
    dmnstatus
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|stop_vms|restart|force-reload|status|setup}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Ok I have downloaded the script and change `VERSION=5.0.12` to `VERSION=5.0.14`. I ran `sudo sh ./rcvboxdrv.sh setup` in `/sbin` and I got this error: http://pastebin.com/raw/j0kynqV0

Comment: @Frank. Well, I did run the script without any change (still version 5.0.12) and it did resolve the issue.  Anyway, this is a known problem, already reported on the Oracle's bugtracker: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15055 . Anyways, there are two other solutions/walkarounds. You can see them as answers and comments to http://askubuntu.com/questions/724184/virtualbox-rcvboxdrv-setup-error-bad-argument-setup