# Error trying to start Virtual Box to add a .ISO

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

When try to start a virtual machine I get these error messages:

[image: error message 1]

> The virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). NS_ERROR_FAILURE

[image: error message 2]

> Kernel driver not installed: The Virtualbox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing '/sbin/vboxconfig' as root. VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908)

Comment: A few things before someone can answer your question. You should really make the title so that it's in English. You should also copy the text of the errors and paste it into your question (translated, of course, to English). That way, it's searchable for future users/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)