# VirtualBox on 16.10 Fails "Kernel Driver Not Installed"

Tags: virtualbox, 16.10

"Failed to start LSB"

Error persists when I try to purge/reinstall per other advice.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

I'm pretty noob, but it seems insane that I would need to disable Secure Boot just to run a common application. Is this really the case? Could someone explain this in clear/simple/novice terms? I'm shocked by the idea that I can't boot up a RHEL virtualbox because my actual Ubuntu installation has secure boot enabled. Isn't secure boot a good thing? I feel like almost every developer on Earth should be able to run VirtualBox from within a secure-booting installation of Ubuntu, but maybe that's not true.

Maybe I just need to do the purge-reinstall with secure boot disabled, then I can re-enable it?

Comment: What purge/reinstall? Per what advice?

Comment: added to question

Comment: Why are you manually installing Virtualbox like that? You can install it directly from the official repositories and that **will** work. Alternatively, for a newer version, you can install the *.deb files from here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads (this will also add VB's PPA and keep it updated).

Comment: The way I installed it was I just went to virtualbox homepage and followed their directions. I can see my .deb file  I installed from was named identically and same size to the one on the download page you linked. virtualbox-5.1_5.1.12-112440~Ubuntu~yakkety_amd64.deb

The other commands are advice for how to fix "Kernel Driver not installed" along with "Failed to start LSB". This fix supposedly worked for versions 12.04-16.04

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Then that error typically happens when you have one Virtualbox installed with guest additions, try to install a newer one and there's a version mismatch. Usually uninstalling the guest additions first work.

Comment: @CelticWarrior
I didn't have guest additions. I just double-clicked the deb file listed above, and pressed Install. Then the error was there. Now, I've run the recommended steps, and the same errors persist.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm pretty noob, but it seems insane that I would need to disable Secure Boot just to run a common application. Is this really the case? Could someone explain this in clear/simple/novice terms? I'm shocked by the idea that I can't boot up a RHEL virtualbox because my actual Ubuntu installation has secure boot enabled. Isn't secure boot a good thing? I feel like almost every developer on Earth should be able to run VirtualBox from within a secure-booting installation of Ubuntu, but maybe that's not true.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255 Secure Boot is a useless feature. So no problem to disable it.

Comment: Secure boot is a *meh* thing and yes, it must be disabled if you intend to run unsigned modules, which seems to be the case. Installing the version in the repositories wouldn't probably have that issue.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I do not thing VB in repos is signed as all other drivers are not.

Comment: @Pilot6 So it would have triggered the same error with secure boot enabled?

Comment: It is easy to test by `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)