# Vagrant + vbox on server 16.04 - how to get it working?

Tags: server, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to setup vagrant with virtual box on my ubuntu server 16.04.
Atm I think that the error I get is due to I miss a GUI.
0x80004005 is the error it spits out.
First I thought is was a permissons error but no, after a while I reinstalled all software packages. Still no luck.

Anyone has any suggestions what I am dong wrong?

This is my output:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
Command: ["startvm", "bd4ed1d2-8ddc-4faa-b993-9ab4526e80ab", "--type", "headless"]
Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'admin_default_1496300210785_96841' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

Comment: The error may indicate that VirtuaBox kernel modules were not installed correctly or there was a version mismatch. Reinstalling VirtualBox may help. It is not related to a missing GUI.

Comment: How do I check the versions so they correlate?

Comment: I reinstalled the kernel modules and after this it works! I found this page to reinstall the modules: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed

Comment: Great news! I hope it is OK with you that we close your question here to direct people to the solution you found.

Comment: Can you explain why are you installing vagrant on ubuntu server i just want to learn...at the moment it just doesn't make any sense to me