# Upgrade to 17.10, wifi and bluetooth 'adapters' not found

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, 17.10

I appreciate you taking the time to read my post, I understand that the wifi thing is super common at the moment but so far what has worked for others isn't working for me.

I'm not sure what info you need from me, but to start with I've tried to fix my wifi.

I went to try this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513

It was already in the file... so that didn't work. I've run dozens of commands in terminal, to no avail. I decided to check my driver for my xps13:

broadcom 802.11 linux sta wireless driver source from bcmwl kernel source (proprietary)

I did some research and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 279336 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 4.13.0-16-lowlatency
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for kernel 4.13.0-16-lowlatency was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.32+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.125ubuntu12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-lowlatency
cryptsetup: WARNING: target cryptswap1 has a random key, skipped
```

I'm not sure if this moving in the right direction but there seem to be a number of issues here - all I'm after at least is some advice as to what steps I should take in resolving these issues.

Thanks for your time.
Wilax

Answer (score 2):

Please note:

> Module build for kernel 4.13.0-16-lowlatency was skipped since the
>   kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Let's try to install them:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
```

Now retry:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Hi I originally tried this however it was skipping parts of the install and seemed to error out. I've managed to get the issue fixed, I've added it as an answer below.

But thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2):

Wilax's colleague's solution can be simplified by installing the lowlatency headers with apt, rather than downloading a specific version. That way they'll be upgraded properly when the kernel is upgraded in the future.

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-lowlatency
```

Comment: As per https://askubuntu.com/a/229908/49860 this also fixed VirtualBox for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaroud for this pb :

As the pb seems to be linked with the low-latency module/kernel, I restart my PC booting on grub option (more options) .. and choosing the same kernel, but the "standart" one (none the "low latency" one)

then up-comming to the session, re-install :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then it's done .. WIFI be back !

Hope could help some one

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your help with this, however my work colleague fixed my issue, posting it here to see if it helps anyone. (Really Simple)

Going to this website:

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/artful/main/base/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-lowlatency

Allowed me to download and install: linux-headers-4.13.0-16-lowlatency

This fired up my wifi and bluetooth drivers so it's all working as expected.