# Can't open gnome-control-center on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: settings, gnome-control-center

So I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and I noticed that "settings" looks limited.

[image]

Also if I go in the terminal and I write `gnome-control-center` nothing happens, no errors, nothing.

I tried to check if it was installed with `sudo apt install unity-control-center` (it was).
And I also used `sudo update-manager`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Settings* app = `gnome-control-center` (and `gnome-control-center` != `unity-control-center`).

Nothing happened after running `gnome-control-center` because I presume you have Settings already open.

To check this, close Settings first and then run `gnome-control-center`. It should launch Settings again.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks a lot.
I just don't know why my setting are so limited.
This is my display window:

 https://imgur.com/a/cK3L9

This is a display window that i found on the web: 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK9ep.png
Can you help me?

Comment: @CristianLoIacono See if this helps with the Wi-Fi adapter issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/968276/upgrade-to-17-10-wifi-and-bluetooth-adapters-not-found. The display window "found on the web" doesn't look like a 17.10 one. Looks like display settings for an (older) version of Ubuntu with Unity.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to change the scaling and I was wondering why the display's window wouldn't let me do it.
But that's how Ubuntu 17.10 is made, I found the fix here though:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux