# VirtualBox won't boot the VM, I tried almost everything

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I have an issue with VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 . It won't boot my windows VM.

When I try to boot the VM, this shows up:

```
The virtual machine 'Windows 10' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).


Fehlercode:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Komponente:
MachineWrap
Interface:
IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}
```

and in another window:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

After the installation, I noticed this:

```
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-10-18 18:09:31 CEST; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9827 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu virtualbox[9827]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu virtualbox[9827]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu virtualbox[9827]:    ...fail!
Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 18 18:09:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

I've already tried reinstalling everything, and almost everything I found on the internet, but nothing is working.

I would really appreciate if somebody can help me. :)

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot in UEFI. That's probably what's preventing the VB drivers to load.

Comment: How did you install virtualbox? Please run `lsmod | grep vbox` and post it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Comment: Did you install virtual-box from the Ubuntu Software Center or from the terminal?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen "apt install ..."

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem after updating Ubuntu:

Please, try reinstalling virtualbox-dkms:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms`

I found this suggestion here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2320523.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 18.04 I did

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
```

after that i downloaded the latest .deb file from 
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

and installed it using `gdebi`

It worked and none of my vms were lost.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked this way

I uninstalled it using

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

And then I downloaded latest version of virtual box from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads and installed it.

None of my vm's were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install **vboxdrv** kernel module?

When you install virtualbox throught APT, vboxdrv already exists.

Follow the instructions in the log:

Try

`modprobe vboxdrv`

You have to install the kernel module as root.