# Unable to start VirtualBox VM on Ubuntu - Kernel driver not installed

Tags: virtualbox

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and would like to learn more in a safer environment than using my host machine. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.3.1 and am struggling to create a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM.

When I try to start the machine I get:

[image: Virtualbox]

Running `modprobe xboxdrv` as root I get:

```
modprobe xboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module xboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.1-050301-generic
```

When I run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

I get

```
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.2.32-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) over (5.2.32-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.32-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1) ... 
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.32 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.1-050301-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.1-050301-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.3.1-050301-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.1-050301-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/make.log for more information.
```

The mentioned file contains this:

```
CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mpnotification-r0drv-linux.o
CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/process-r0drv-linux.o
CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/rtStrFormatKernelAddress-r0drv-linux.o
CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semevent-r0drv-linux.o
CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semeventmulti-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.c:
In function ‘VBoxHost_RTMpOnAll’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.c:287:18:
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
         int rc = smp_call_function(rtmpLinuxAllWrapper, &Args, 0 /* wait */);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.c:
In function ‘VBoxHost_RTMpOnOthers’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.c:341:8:
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     rc = smp_call_function(rtmpLinuxWrapper, &Args, 1 /* wait */);
        ^ scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.o'
failed make[2]: ***
[/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.o]
Error 1 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   CC [M] 
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semfastmutex-r0drv-linux.o
scripts/Makefile.build:497: recipe for target
'/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv' failed
 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build/vboxdrv]
 Error 2 Makefile:1624: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build' failed
 make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.2.32/build]
 Error 2 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.1-050301-generic'
```

How do I get VirtualBox running on Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try disabling "Safe Boot" from your machine's BIOS?

Comment: Yes, I've disabled this.

Comment: I think your kernel is to new.  better to use oracle virtualbox https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score 3):

VirtualBox doesn't work with kernel 5.3 yet, so either downgrade to kernel 5.2 or wait for VirtualBox update that fixes this (or patch it yourself).

Comment: How would I go about patching it myself? Also, how long does it usually take for them to update the fix?

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox 6.0.14 now contains the fix: [changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog)
[guide for upgrading](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/10/virtualbox-6-0-14-linux-5-3-support/)

Comment: I am running VirtualBox Version 6.1.14 r140239 (Qt5.9.5) and am still running into this problem with no solution.