# "Kernel driver not installed" when trying to start a Virtualbox VM in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, virtualbox, dkms

When I try to open an OS on virtual box then it shows `kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)`.Please tell me what to do. My OS is ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please edit your question and add your OS type and release so we can help you better

Comment: Try: Install the `virtualbox-dkms` package on your Ubuntu host (not guest)

Comment: Open your terminal and cut/paste this: `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic -y ; sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y; sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox -y`

Comment: Did the above resolve your VirtualBox issue? If so, you'll want to keep that command copied and ready for the next time the kernel updates. You'll need to re-run it every time, but it only takes a few minutes. If it did resolve your issue, I'll write out a more complete answer to explain it.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic -y ; sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y; sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox -y` but still there is a persistent problem with dkms: [output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mD4T9vdjx5/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)