# I never can start any virtual machine in virtualbox! : Error “Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)”

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I installed **VirtualBox** using `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`.

Every time I try to start a virtual machine, I get this error:

[image: img_kernel-driver]

I logged in as root, and typed this into the terminal: `modprobe vboxdrv` and I got another error:

[image: img_terminal_error]

I also got another error:

[image: img_virtualbox_error]

(More info: I am using Ubuntu 16.04)

Help!!!

Comment: Support for Ubuntu 16.04 ended this month (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Are you willing to upgrade to a newer supported version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Turn off secure boot.

Comment: What does secure boot have to do with VirtualBox?

Comment: *What does secure boot have to do with VirtualBox?* Everything. Secure Boot prevents unsigned drivers like the ones Virtualbox depends on from loading. Either disable Secure Boot in UEFI, by far the easiest option and use mokutil to "trust" those drivers (not for newbies, at all).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall the `virtualbox-dkms` package by running the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Comment: Reinstalling stuff hoping that it'll work stems from a certain "Windows mentality". No, it won't work in this case. The situation has been correctly identified in comments and this question is off-topic.