# I can't run a Windows executable using Wine!

Tags: wine

I tried to run vmware.exe through Wine but I got a weird empty error message box and the application did not run:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to run a Windows version of VMware with Wine? VMware has a Linux version... https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_install_linux.html

Comment: The reason I want to run the Windows version is that the Linux version does not run because I could not get gcc to work on VMware: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331438/i-cant-use-vmware-on-ubuntu

Comment: Why doesn't gcc work?

Comment: GCC does not work because VMware said `a compatible version of GCC was not found` when I entered the location `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: @lulupuppy which Ubuntu version are you using?  And which VMware version?  Vmware **does not** run within Wine and never will because it requires a lot of system level services.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and VMware 16. But can very early versions of VMware run in Wine?

Comment: @lulupuppy No, because VMware still has system kernel services.  Ubuntu 16.04 is tool old to run VMware 16, you'll need to upgrade to 18.04 or newer for a newer `gcc` version.  Or find an installer for VMware 12 - 14 because I believe those are old enough to run in Linux natively.  Also keep in mind that Ubuntu 16.04 goes past end of standard support in less than a month (and at that point will be past support here on Ask Ubuntu), so I would advise looking to upgrade your system to 18.04 sooner than later.

Comment: Try virtualbox instead. It is available in the Ubuntu's official repositories.

Comment: I already tried to install virtualbox and this is what happened: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331246/i-never-can-start-any-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox