# Need Help with VM Software

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have been trying all day to set a VM software on my Ubuntu system, but it seems like no matter what I do, Virtualbox nor VMWare are working! I've given it my all, but can't find the solution.

Virtualbox pops this up:

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing


'modprobe vboxdrv'


as root.


If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.


where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

The virtual machine 'test' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code:


NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Component:


MachineWrap

Interface:


IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

VMWare gives me:

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.

Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

None of these kernel modules work. Any help is big help.

EDIT: I have fixed it! Thank all of you! Also, this was my personal PC I was trying to test different Linux distros on a VM. Thanks again!

Thanks.

Comment: try updating your system be apt update&&apt upgrade or try reinstalling vm

Comment: What is the output of `sudo modprobe vmmon` and `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`?

Comment: Also, it says to reinstall the `virtualbox-dkms` so you would need to run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms` and then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and finally reboot.

Comment: This is *your* system, right? Not a VPS or some other cloud instance?

Comment: Notice that you might have to enable virtualization in the BIOS first. Also, some old CPU types don't have support for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)