# 22.04 Windows Virtualbox Kernal Drivers Error

Tags: virtualbox

[When I try to run this Windows instance, it gives me an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdaql.png)

This is my first time using virtual box, If you need any further information, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed)